# JSlint - 'function' was used before it was defined'

Tags: javascript, jslint

I've just started using JSlint to see if I can improve my code.  It's quite...pedantic but very useful.

I currently have the issue whereby a function is being called but jslint is telling me it's not yet been defined.

The function is a simple generate random number function and it's stored in a generic 'helper file'.  I don't want to or see the need in copying this function into every file where it's called, kinda defeats the purpose of the helper file :)

Is there something else that I'm missing?  I can't help but think I'm making an amateur mistake but can't see it for looking.

The error is being presented on this line : `randomNum = random_num(layerDetails.length);`

and the random_num function is simply:

`function random_num($value) {
    $result = Math.floor(Math.random() * $value);
    return $result;
}`

thanks for any help.  I'd like jslint to give me clean bill of health so to speak.

Comment: At the bottom of the JSLint page, just below the Options, is a white box. List any external or global functions you call in there. BTW, Douglas Crockford has some good ideas, but not all of them are necessarily black and white. You might like to take a look at [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) as an alternative.

Comment: um...I'm running it from the terminal.  :) - I was scanning all files in the project folder using node, is there perhaps an alternative way?

Comment: You can also simply concatenate all your JS files together and then jsLint that concatenated file.  This simulates what happens when the browser loads them all your scripts in a given page and this way all functions you have declared will be available when they would actually be available in the browser so JSLint is getting a clearer total picture.

Comment: @jfriend00 - that sounds like an ideal solution and would avoid having the jslint comments at the top of each file.  Could you explain how to do it pleasE?

Comment: If you're just doing this once in a while, you can just copy/paste them all into a temporary master file in your editor (in the right order).  If you want a tool, there are hundreds of tools for concatenating javascript files (most also have the ability to minify which you don't need).  YUI compressor is one, but there are literally hundreds of others you will encounter with a Google search for "javascript file concatenation".

Comment: As soon as I replied I was 'Googling' :) Found a few, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a global function which is also a global variable. Globals are generally a bad thing because they eat up your namespace and cause naming collisions.

If you're not worried about that you can let JSLint know which globals you are using by adding the following comment to the top of each file you lint:

```
/*globals random_num, $ */
```

I've added `$` to demonstrate that you can provide a list of globals.

However since you're using Node I'd recommend adding this to a `Utils` module. JSLint will not complain about that since you'll be declaring the module with `var`.

utils.js

```
module.exports = {
  random_num: function random_num($value) {
    $result = Math.floor(Math.random() * $value);
    return $result;
  }
};
```

Elsewhere:

```
var utils = require('./utils');
utils.random_num();
```

Comment: thank you!  I used similar to avoid the ++ issue in loops.  I know that a global variable is bad but this function...surely it's better to have it in one place available globally than to have it in many separate files?  Could you explain what yo mean by utils module?

Comment: It's usually better to organize your code into modules. And I always try to aim for a namespace of the maximum possible size, in general it reduces the likelihood that you will "run out of" variable names in any given context.

Comment: Added utils module example.

Comment: Thanks!  that helps a lot, I guess i now need to refactor some more code :D

Comment: JSlint didn't like 'globals' btw.  not sure why

Comment: Depending on the implementation of JSLint it may be "global" singular rather than plural.

Comment: the global code was /*global random_num: true */ - found on http://www.jslint.com/lint.html